# Better way to create a flaskform and display it

Tags: python, flask

In py file:

```
class form(flaskform):
form1 = DecimalField("00:00", validators=[InputRequired()])
form2 = DecimalField("00:10", validators=[InputRequired()])
.
.
.
form50 = DecimalField("00.xx, validators=[InputRequired()])
```

Is there a way to simplify this? I don't want to write 100 lines of code if I want a 100 forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Form(n=100):
    class TempForm(FlaskForm):
        pass
    for i in range(n):
         setattr(TempForm, 'form{}'.format(i+1), 
                 DecimalField('00.{}'.format(i*10), validators= 
                 [InputRequired()])

    return TempForm()
```

Comment: Great, I will try this out in a few hours. May I know where can I read more about these kind of syntax? All I found was those beginner level python tutorial and never came across this format.

Comment: To be honest I never came across it in basic tutorials but learned by trial and error and coming up against a real practical problem like you did. This is associated with 'dynamic wtforms'

Comment: @calvert, please accept the answer by selecting the tick if it solves prob.

Comment: Do you know by any chance display the form using html? Your code gives no errors but I couldn't display it on a webpage.

Comment: Pass your form in the render_template: `form=Form()` then in a jinja2 loop over `i` just reference a form field with `{{ form['form' +(i+1) | string] }}` using the jinja2 filter casting.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I tried to give your comment +1 but it seems like my account is too young to do so.

Comment: @calvert you can always accept the answer, by using the tick, upvoting and accepting are different - but the question poser can always accept, whilst most accounts can upvote and downvote